# FB ui feed get message after posting on wall

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using this function to initiate a UI feed to post on my wall a content from my website. :

```
 FB.ui({
      method: 'feed',
      name: myname,
      link: window.location.href,
      picture: mypic,
      caption: '',
      description: desc
    },function(response){}
  });
```

I need to execute a callback inside the callback in which I can retrieve the message that the I inserted in the Facebook Dialog, I'm searching but not finding a way to get it, I also tried to delegate a keydown event to the dialog's textarea , but It does not work.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You want to retrieve the actual post that was created?

Comment: I want to retrieve the message that was attacched from the user to it, like "Look at this awesome video" when sharing a video.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to extract data from the post that was created from the dialog you can retrieve the `post_id` from within the callback function that the dialog provides. Within the callback you'll be able to inspect the `response` object. It will contain the `post_id` provided that the post was successfully created.

With this `post_id` you can execute an additional call to the API and provide the post_id` as the endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID
```

Or with the JavaScript SDK:

```
FB.api( '/POST_ID', function( response ) {
  console.log( response );
} );
```

Take a look at the response object from the second call, it'll look something like this :

```
{
  "id": "POST_ID", 
  "from": {
    "name": "Lix", 
    "id": "XXXYYY"
  }, 
  "message": "Checkout this awesome link!", 
  "picture": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/...", 
  ...
}
```

As you can see, the message is contained in the response, so to enhance my previous example:

```
FB.api( '/POST_ID', function( response ) {
  if ( response ){
    console.log( response.message );
  }
} );
```

And now we can put it all together with the `FB.ui` call:

```
 FB.ui({
      method: 'feed',
      ...
    },function( response ){
      if ( response && response.post_id ){
        FB.api( '/' + response.post_id, function( response ) {
          console.log( response );
        } );
      }
    }
  });
```